# How to set location based in country name when latitude and longitude is 0 (null)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

For example, I have some fields with 0 for latitude and longitude.

[image]

This happen because in the database, those columns are null (longitude and latitude is unknown).

[image]

How can I simply set the country name for latitude and longitude 0? (in this case, the blue point for latitude 0 and longitude 0 should be in the center of Brazil country, without any exact location).

Edit: the behavior for those columns with 0 for latitude and longitude should be the same when using the field location instead of latitude and longitude, like it:

[image]

Comment: You need to know where "the center of the country" is.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a table with countries and their center lat/long coordinates, and join in this table with your sample table to enrich your data where you now have nulls.